# Does Wikipedia uses Mobilefrontend extension AND mobile subomains at the same time?

Tags: mediawiki, wikipedia, wikipedia-api, mediawiki-extensions

I have setup a Mediawiki family and installed the [Mediawiki Mobilefrontend Extension](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Extension:MobileFrontend) for better mobile usability.

The extension documentation says that it is used on Wikimedia projects (like Wikipedia).

The extension gives the same look as what Wikipdia looks like on mobile, however, I noticed a big difference.

The Wikipedia on mobile seems to go to a mobile subdomain, in addition to the format that the Moileforntend Extension provides.

for example, a page about the "World Cup" has this url when viewed on a desktop computer:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/World_Cup

while it has this url when viewed from a mobile phone:
https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/World_Cup

**My questions are:**

1- Is this really a redirection to a mobile subdomain? or a mirror installation?

2- What are the benefits of redirecting to a subdomain while the Mobiefrontend extension provides the formatting already.

3- How does the data gets synchronized between the main site and the mobile site?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is mentioned in [this part of the configuration](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Extension:MobileFrontend/Configuring_browser_auto-detection#Detection_using_Varnish:_mobile_site_on_another_domain).

Comment: I appreciate the resource but it does not answer at least part 2 of OP’s query: “2. What are the benefits of redirecting to a sub domain...?”

Comment: I couldn't find a reference explaining directly the differences. Not sure if there are real differences.